# jib: Invalid volume path when creating docker image using jib

Tags: docker, jib

I am using jib to build my spring boot war file for tomcat.

I am using a local tomcat docker image.

I use gradle jibDockerBuild --stacktrace and i get the following error:

```
caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.image.json.BadContainerConfigurationFormatException: Invalid volume path: [
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.image.json.JsonToImageTranslator.volumeMapToSet(JsonToImageTranslator.java:268)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.image.json.JsonToImageTranslator.configureBuilderWithContainerConfiguration(JsonToImageTranslator.java:201)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.image.json.JsonToImageTranslator.toImage(JsonToImageTranslator.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LocalBaseImageSteps.lambda$returnImageAndRegistryClientStep$2(LocalBaseImageSteps.java:171)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.StepsRunner.lambda$assignLocalImageResult$4(StepsRunner.java:289)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
```

I am able to run the image with docker run and docker-compose.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 0):

Your base tomcat image in the local Docker daemon has incorrect volume configuration values. We have seen the [exact same case](https://gitter.im/google/jib?at=5dcab44de75b2d5a19bc3d32) in the past.

> got an older base image based on a older revision of centos/systemd
> where a volume is defined using `[[ <volume-path> ]]` pattern. this does
> not seem to work at all Is that supposed to be supported?
>
> ```
> Caused by:
> com.google.cloud.tools.jib.image.json.BadContainerConfigurationFormatException:
> Invalid volume path: [
> ```
>
> rebasing the image on the very latest centos/systemd seems to work where the same volume is defined as `[ <volume-path> ]`

In that case, `docker inspect` showed that `Volumes` was set to

```
"Volumes": {
    "[": {},
    "]": {},
    "â€œ/sys/fs/cgroupâ€": {}
}
```

which is a map from string (volume path) -> literal {}, meaning that it defines three volume paths (map entries): `[`, `]`, `â€œ/sys/fs/cgroupâ€`. And of course, `]` and `[` are not a valid absolute UNIX path.

A correct setting will look like

```
"Volumes": {
    "/my/volume/dir": {},
    "/another/volume": {}
},
```

where each entry is a map from an absolute UNIX path to `{}`.

Fixing the `Volumes` configuration of your tomcat image will resolve the issue.